# Another Series $\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\log(k)}{k}\sin(2k \mu \pi)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I ran across an interesting series in a [paper](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN599484047_0023&DMDID=DMDLOG_0038&LOGID=LOG_0041&PHYSID=PHYS_0150) written by J.W.L. Glaisher. Glaisher mentions that it is a known formula but does not indicate how it can be derived.

I think it is difficult.

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\log(k)}{k}\sin(2k \mu \pi) = \pi \left(\log(\Gamma(\mu)) +\frac{1}{2}\log \sin(\pi \mu)-(1-\mu)\log(\pi)- \left(\frac{1}{2}-\mu\right)(\gamma+\log 2)\right)$$

Can someone suggest a method of attack?

$\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni Constant.

Thank You!

Comment: $\mu$ is an arbitrary constant?

Comment: @J.M: Yes, its an arbitrary constant.

Comment: Where did you run across the series?

Comment: It might help to notice that $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\frac1{k^x}=-\frac{\log\,k}{k^x}$. This means that the [Clausen function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function) will somehow be involved.

Comment: I found this series in a paper called "On Certain Numerical Products In Which The Exponents Depends Upon The Numbers". It is written by J.W.L. Glaisher. He says that it is a known formula but does not indicate how it can be derived.

Comment: You might want to [link to it](http://resolver.sub.uni-goettingen.de/purl?PPN599484047_0023/DMDLOG_0038) in the question...

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is the same paper in which I found the series.

Comment: Maybe it can be done like this:  the right-hand side is a certain function of $\mu$.  Show that the left-hand side is the Fourier series of that function.

Comment: Note it is valid only for $0 < \mu < 1$.  The left side has period $1$, but the right side doesn't.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It suffices to do these integrals:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \log(\Gamma(s))\;ds &= \frac{\log(2\pi)}{2}
\tag{1a}\\
\int_0^1 \log(\Gamma(s))\;\cos(2k \pi s)\;ds &= \frac{1}{4k},\qquad k \ge 1
\tag{1b}\\
\int_0^1 \log(\Gamma(s))\;\sin(2k \pi s)\;ds &= \frac{\gamma+\log(2k\pi)}{2k\pi},\qquad k \ge 1
\tag{1c}
\\
\int_0^1 \frac{\log(\sin(\pi s))}{2}\;ds &= \frac{-\log 2}{2}
\tag{2a}
\\
\int_0^1 \frac{\log(\sin(\pi s))}{2}\;\cos(2k \pi s)\;ds &= \frac{-1}{4k},\qquad k \ge 1
\tag{2b}
\\
\int_0^1 \frac{\log(\sin(\pi s))}{2}\;\sin(2k \pi s)\;ds &= 0,\qquad k \ge 1
\tag{2c}
\\
\int_0^1 1 \;ds &= 1
\tag{3a}
\\
\int_0^1 1 \cdot \cos(2k \pi s)\;ds &= 0,\qquad k \ge 1
\tag{3b}
\\
\int_0^1 1 \cdot \sin(2k \pi s)\;ds &= 0,\qquad k \ge 1
\tag{3c}
\\
\int_0^1 s \;ds &= \frac{1}{2}
\tag{4a}
\\
\int_0^1 s \cdot \cos(2k \pi s)\;ds &= 0,\qquad k \ge 1
\tag{4b}
\\
\int_0^1 s \cdot \sin(2k \pi s)\;ds &= \frac{-1}{2k\pi},\qquad k \ge 1
\tag{4c}
\end{align}
$$
Then for $f(s) = \pi \left(\log(\Gamma(s)) +\frac{1}{2}\log \sin(\pi s)-(1-s)\log(\pi)- \left(\frac{1}{2}-s\right)(\gamma+\log 2)\right)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f(s)\;ds &= 0
\\
2\int_0^1f(s) \cos(2k\pi s)\;\;ds &= 0,\qquad k \ge 1
\\
2\int_0^1f(s) \sin(2k\pi s)\;\;ds &= \frac{\log k}{k},\qquad k \ge 1
\end{align}
$$
and the formula follows as a Fourier series:
$$
f(s) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\log k}{k}\;\sin(2 k\pi s),\qquad 0 < s < 1.
$$

**reference**

Gradshteyn & Ryzhik, *Table of Integrals Series and Products*

(1a) 6.441.2
(1b) 6.443.3
(1c) 6.443.1
(2a) 4.384.3
(2b) 4.384.3
(2c) 4.384.1

Answer (score 1):

That is the well-known Fourier expansion of $\log\Gamma(x)$ due to Kummer from 1847. The article of Glaisher is from 1893. See
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gammafunktion